# Possible Worlds Semantics and Modal Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, modal-logic

Kripke's Possible Worlds Semantics, with reflectivity, transitivity and equivalence properties, is compliant with the Modal Logic axiomatic system K4.

Is this a complete and sound formal system ?

ps: i come from FOL, so i'm sorry if what i wrote is inaccurate...

Comment: Yes; you can see Saul Kripke, [A Completeness Theorem in Modal Logic](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2964568?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), JSL (1959) as well as a textbook, like e.g. James Garson, [Modal Logic for Philosophers](https://books.google.it/books?id=rFpbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PR5), Cambridge UP (2006).

Comment: See also [Modal Logic : Possible Worlds Semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#PosWorSem) and [Basic Concepts in Modal Logic](https://mally.stanford.edu/notes.pdf).